# Can had inversion occur in past tense, not past perfect?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

> If the man had his life partner, he would be very happy.
>
> Had the man his life partner, he would be very happy.

Is this inversion valid? I have learned that Had inversion only occurs in past perfect tense and also I can't find any example that represents Had inversion occuring in past tense.

Comment: In American English, that would not be the way to say it. When _have_ is not an auxiliary, but a verb meaning 'possess', it acts like a normal verb and requires _Do_-support when inversion or contraction requires an auxiliary, but this kind of archaic artificial transformation from an _if_-clause seems even sillier with _Do_-support: _??Did he have his life partner, he would be very happy._

Comment: @JohnLawler I keep wanting to call you "Bugsy".

Comment: No relation, apparently. :-)

Comment: @John I would asterisk that double-question-mark. _If_-clause inversion is a different beast than regular inversion – it is much more restricted. It’s completely unavailable as an option not only to nearly all lexical verbs, but also to modals (which otherwise allow inversion) and even to some auxiliaries (like passive _get_). It is basically available to no other verb than _have_ and _be_, the latter in all senses (auxiliary and predicative), the former only as an auxiliary in AmE, but also as a lexical verb in BrE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, but such a usage will be considered stuffy.

In the prologue of  Canterbury Tales, in the introduction of the Dr. of Phisick, we see

> Full ready had he his 'Pothecaries, To send him druggis and 'lectuaries,...

Samuel Richardson's 1748 epistolary novel *Clarissa, Or: the History of a young Lady*, has this:

> And thus, as Mr. Lovelace thought fit to take it, had he his answer from my sister.

Modern inversions of this sort are typically a way of expressing [conditional mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood).

We have this in a 1965 Harlan Ellison review of the movie *The Train* in *Cinema* magazine:

> Unlike most of the flea-marketeers of Hollywood, director John Frankenheimer is a man who would deal with whales, **had he his choice**.

Piers Anthony's book *Aliena Too* has

> **Had he his choice** of a perfect world, he would never have left her. But that kind of choice he never had.

You're unlikely to see this outside of poetry and literature, however. It's  a little stuffy, verging on idiomatic, because in ordinary conversational English one would typically say "If I had my choice" rather than "Had I my choice".

Also see [this old EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95741/even-were-he-not-to).

Comment: Marvell provides the most obvious example: "Had we but world enough and time, /
This coyness, lady, were no crime."

Comment: I presume _’le&tuaries_ is a typo – _lectuaries_? // There are some cases where an inverted non-auxiliary _have_ conditional would not be considered archaic (at least not in BrE). Something like, “Had I the time, I would…” strikes me as being a bit on the formal side, but hardly archaic. Yeats’ “Had they but courage equal to desire” is poetic and old-timey, but also not really archaic.

Comment: @Janus Oops, I missed that OCR error. I think you missed my transitional paragraph introducing the modern restriction of this usage to the conditional.

Comment: @Spencer No, I saw that – I was commenting on your first sentence that “such a usage will be considered archaic”. The example in the question, I agree, sounds archaic, even in BrE; but there are other, similar conditional examples that just sound formal or a bit old-timey, not archaic. (I also think the inverted conditional in general is likely to be more common in the north of England than elsewhere, but I’ve nothing to back that up other than a vague hunch.)

Comment: @Janus Notice my two recent literary examples were by Americans.

Comment: That actually surprises me – particularly the second one, which Google tells me is from 2014. But then I suppose that’s literature, where even Americans sometimes get a bit stuffy. :-þ

Comment: @Janus Anyway, I hope I've toned it down enough for you.